# edit uploaded docx file in PHP

Tags: php, openxml, docx

I need to open uploaded `.docx` file and possibility to change values. I know, that `docx` file consists of `xml` files. So, the main question is maybe somebody know a good WYSIWYG web-based xml editor?
 I know one called `XOPUS`, but i have no idea how to configure it. Maybe somebody knows other alternatives for that task or advices, how to put `xml` file to textfield, where i could change values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of PHP toolkits that you can use for this task, first off there's an early dev on on codeplex:

```
http://openxmlapi.codeplex.com/
```

However you may b better off with one of the more mature ones:

```
http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/index.html
http://www.phpdocx.com/
```

Both of these can convert from docx to most of the popular formats, HTML included.

Once you've converted to something like HTML, then you can use an onscreen editor such as tiny MCE:

```
http://www.tinymce.com/
```

To provide in page rich editing capabilities, before finally using the above toolkits to convert back to DOCX or any other applicable format.

## Update February 2014

Since I first wrote this reply things have moved on.  The open xml kits I mentioned above are still valid, however in page editing is now more of a possibility than ever using the new HTML5 content editable and edit mode attributes.

It's now insanely easy to add your own buttons (Using something like bootstrap) above a div that has a content editable attribute attached to it.

Connecting the buttons to "document.execCommand" can then send, bold, italic, underline, link & image creation, list insertion and all manner of other HTML constructions methods directly to this div without needing anything like tinyMce or another in page editor anymore.

There is full details available on the Mozilla developer network, and I am planning o do a blog post on using this stuff very soon.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: as far as I know it can create document from template, but not edit. Or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One may use the DocxUtilities class of [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com) to do some partial editing of an existing Word document.

This class allows you for:

1. searching and replacing a particular string of text
2. searching a string of text and remove the containing paragraph or section
3. highlight predefined strings (search and highlight)
4. full merging of docx files (text, images, charts, footnotes, ...)

If that is not enough for your purposes you should then prepare a PHPDocX template to fully customized an existing Word document.